# how to set state of textinput react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, textinput

I'm just learning react Native, but why doesn't the editable change to true when I press the button?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { isWrong: false };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextInput editable={this.state.isWrong} />
        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState.isWrong = true;
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.setState({ isWrong: true })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` is a **function**

```
const new_values = { isWrong: true };
this.setState(new_values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Somthing like this should help:

```
<TextInput editable={this.state.isWrong} />
<Button
  onPress={()=> this.setState({ isWrong: true })} >
</Button>
```